# Filter on minimum number of records (COUNT) matching condition

Tags: mysql

I would like to select records from a single table based on a minimum number of records (N) for a particular person. For example, if N=2, then

```
Name  Time
John  09:00:00
Sam   09:05:00
Sally 09:06:00
John  09:10:00
Jane  09:15:00
Joe   09:16:00
Sally 09:22:00
```

filters down to

```
Name  Time
John  09:00:00
Sally 09:06:00
John  09:10:00
Sally 09:22:00
```

It is easy to count the records but how do I select them?

Answer (score 0):

use group by function.

```
select count(*),Name  from table_name group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select * 
from mytable 
where name in (
    select name 
    from mytable 
    group by name 
    having count(1) =2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first group your records by the number of times a particular person occurs:

```
select count(1), name
from   Person
group  by name;
```

Next, you want to select those persons that occur twice or more:

```
select name, time
from   Person
where  id in (
       select id from Person group by name having count(1) >= 2
)
```

Note that I assume your `Person` table has an `id` column which uniquely identifies each column.

So, basically, you first select the `id`s of the persons that occur twice or more, and then select the desired data for those persons.